# R keras package: Python module tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras was not found

Tags: python, r, windows, tensorflow, keras

Windows 7, Python 3.6 (64-bit), RStudio 1.0.143, R 3.4.0

I'm getting this error message even though it's got the correct path to `tensorflow` package:

```
> library(keras)
> data <- dataset_mnist()
Error: Python module tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/mikzhi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
version:        3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.13.1
tensorflow:     C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow
```

Switching to Python 3.5.3 doesn't help:

```
> data <- dataset_mnist()
Error: Python module tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/mikzhi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/python35.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35
version:        3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.13.1
tensorflow:     C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
 C:\Users\mikzhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\\python.exe
```

Comment: Try python3.5. Keras is compatible with Python 2.7-3.5 only at this stage. https://keras.io/

Comment: Am getting the same error. Not sure why it claims to have found two versions (Python35\python.exe and Python35\\python.exe).

Comment: Take a look at this issue in the keras Github repo:https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/37

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix the problem by running `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Perhaps `install_tensorflow()` hadn't done all that was needed.